# Target Objects in yii\data\ArrayDataProvider

Tags: yii2

I am working with a LDAP extension, it queries the Active Directory server and returns the result as a Yii2 ArrayDataProvider.

```
$attributes = Yii::$app->ldap->searchUserByLogin($this->username, ['mail', 'sn', 'givenname']);
```

A vardump of the returned info is as follows;

```
yii\data\ArrayDataProvider#1
(
    [key] => null
    [allModels] => [
        0 => [
            'mail' => ‘test@test.com
            'sn' => ‘Surname’
            'givenname' => ‘FirstName’
            'middlename' => null
        ]
    ]
    [modelClass] => null
    [id] => null
    [yii\data\BaseDataProvider:_sort] => null
    [yii\data\BaseDataProvider:_pagination] => null
    [yii\data\BaseDataProvider:_keys] => null
    [yii\data\BaseDataProvider:_models] => null
    [yii\data\BaseDataProvider:_totalCount] => null
    [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
    [yii\base\Component:_eventWildcards] => []
    [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => null
```

It was my understanding I could treat the data as objects and access them like;

```
$attributes->mail
```

But I get an error that the object isn't found. Then if I try and treat it like a traditional array I get;

```
Cannot use object of type yii\data\ArrayDataProvider as array yii2
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show your `view/xxx.html` code, `ArrayDataProvider` provide an object, I want to know how you use `ArrayDataProvider`?

It seems to be possible in your code to have used this code

```
$attributes['allModels'][0]['mail']
```

which should be like below

```
$results = $attributes->getModels();
```

Comment: ArrayDataProvider provide an array.

Comment: I'm using it in the controller only to create / update the user information from the LDAP server. I get the error `Cannot use object of type yii\data\ArrayDataProvider as array yii2` when I try to access it like a regular array   `$user = new User();
                    $user->username = $this->username;
                    $user->email = $attributes['allModels'][0]['mail'];
                    $user->setPassword($this->password);
                    $user->generateAuthKey();
                    $user->save();`

Comment: Could you show ```var_dump($results = $attributes->getModels());```?

Comment: I can get it now.`$results = $attributes->getModels();` then `$user->email = $results[0]['mail'];` Thank you very much!